# Printf Recursive String Function Odd Behaviour

Tags: c, recursion, printf

I have this recursive string function and a helper function for it which combines two strings(char pointers):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* stringcat(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int length=0;
    int sizes[2];
    int c=0;

    while(s1[c]!='\0')
            ++c;
    length=c;
    sizes[0]=c;
    c=0;
    while(s2[c]!='\0')
            ++c;
    length+=c;
    sizes[1]=c;

    char *comboword=malloc(sizeof(char)*length);

    for(int i=0; i<sizes[0]; i++)
            comboword[i]=s1[i];

    for(int j=sizes[0]; j<length; j++)
            comboword[j]=s2[j-sizes[0]];

return comboword;

}

char* mmfu(int mm)
{
            char* mmm="mm";
            if (mm<=0)
                    return mmm;
            else
                    return stringcat(mmm,mmfu(mm-1));
}
```

I call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int d;
    scanf("%d",&d);

    printf("%s %d\n",mmfu(1),d);
}
```

For d of 1 and 0 the output is as expected, mmmm (d) and mm (d), but for anything over 1, the output is something like ▒{▒ 6mmm (with mmfu(3) and d=6) or ▒{▒ 5m for mmfu(2) and d=5. I can see theres some pattern to the odd output but I'm super confused on why its happening in the first place. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Missed the last "\0" of all strings, didn't you?

Comment: Please explain the "rule" behind your code. Give examples of input and expected output. Use more appropriate formatting for showing the expected output. I am unclear which part of the non-digit and non-"m"s are actually part of the output. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: On a more general level, this might be very helpful (though perceivable as a bit cynical in parts...) https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The length you calculate excludes the terminating null byte.  So `"abc"` would have length 3.  However, you forgot to add the extra null byte when allocating and when copying.  So it's not surprising that it fails.

Comment: @TomKarzes that was it, it works correctly now, thanks!

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for your feedback, I'll try to format my code better in the future, Also appreciate the link!

Comment: @TomKarzes Your comment is the more elaborate one. I intend to make an answer and will more or less use your input (because it basically is what I meant with my first comment, too). Let me know if you want to do the answer, in that case I will refrain. Should my answer be up when you notice this, still notify me. I am then open to have a race and delete mine if yours gets more upvotes.

Comment: Why "in the future". Try to [edit] this question right away. You will anyway need some experience, better get it here before it burdens your next question. Maybe just to please me.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for checking - go ahead and post, I'm a bit lazy these days...

Comment: Might take until tomorrow, or until Azuras_Tsar [edit]s to improve this question...

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *comboword=malloc(sizeof(char)*length);`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the c standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  It also clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.   Suggest removing that expression

Comment: is there some reason you cannot use the C library functions, like `strcat()` and `strlen()`  Note: to use those functions the code will need to have this statement: `#include <string.h>`